# creating Favorite List with AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, save, shared-objects

I'm new with as3 but trying to learn that.
I want to make a Favorite List for my android application which creating with flash professional cs6 , in photo I attached you can understand what I mean.
I created a list dynamically with an array , if you have time please take a look at my fla project to understand better.
I wanted to know can this make it happen with Shared Object or not ? 
any help appreciated

what i mean : (by clicking on star icon , the item in list will save in Favorite List Menu )
http://s5.picofile.com/file/8135187742/Favorite_list.jpg
fla source : 
https://www.sendspace.com/file/rnqjdx

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? can you show some code?

Comment: ty for the reply , if you don't mind please take a look at my project (https://www.sendspace.com/file/rnqjdx) , I just want to know can I do this with SharedObject with an dynamically created movieclips in an array or not ?

Comment: Yes you can use a shared object for you Android Air app